# Rails 3 ActiveRecord find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3, you do like...

User.select(...).include(...).order(...)

However, if you select only 1 record, how do you do that?

User.find(10).include(:pictures) doesn't seem to work.

Should I use User.find(10, :include => [:pictures]) ?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: is that works? seems ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your `User.find(10, :include=>:pictures])` example should work fine. You can also do `User.includes(:pictures).find(10)`.

It doesn't matter too much either way but I'd probably go with the second method since it's more Rails 3ish and less likely to wind up deprecated.